# Iterate and compute over multiple dask arrays

Tags: python, dask

I have multiple dask arrays and would like to save them to a GIF or some movie format using `imageio` one frame at a time, but I think the problem is generic enough that the solution could help other people. I'm wondering if there is a way to compute the arrays in order and while computing one array and writing it to disk, start computing the next one on the remaining workers. If possible, it would be nice if the scheduler/graph could share tasks between the dask arrays if any.

The code would look something like this in my eyes:

```
import dask.array as da
writer = Writer(...)
for dask_arr in da.compute([dask_arr1, dask_arr2, dask_arr3]):
    writer.write_frame(dask_arr)
```

It looks like this is probably hackable by users with the distributed scheduler, but I'd like to use the threaded scheduler if possible. I'm also not sure if this is super useful in my exact real world case given memory usage or possibly having to write entire frames at a time instead of chunks. I also don't doubt that this could be handled in a custom array-like object with `da.store`...some how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're able to write a function that takes in a slice of the array and then writes it appropriately you might be able to use a function like `da.map_blocks`.

This would become much more complex if you're trying to write into a single file where random access is harder to guarantee.

Perhaps you could use `map_blocks` to save each slice as a single image and then use some post-processing tool to stitch those images together.

Comment: Yeah the post processing approach is the obvious workaround. I was hoping to avoid it for the purpose of this and it would make my code much more pythonic if it didn't have to call command line tools afterward.

@Mrocklin Do you think it would be possible for me to add this functionality to the existing features of dask? Or do you think this would require major changes to the schedulers/graph code?

Comment: It's not yet clear to me what you are proposing above.  I recommend that you raise an issue.  You might want to ping `@jakirkham`, who may have an interest in topics like this.

Comment: For reference: a solution was figured out on the github issue linked to above. I'll accept this answer since I know Matt only does stackoverflow for the reputation /s.